# Stylus iteration in selector's attribute

Tags: css, stylus

I am making a site map.

Need something like this as a result:

```
ul.site-map li[data-level="1"] {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
ul.site-map li[data-level="2"] {
  margin-left: 100px;
}
ul.site-map li[data-level="3"] {
  margin-left: 150px;
}
```

This Stylus code doesn't work:

```
ul.site-map
    li
        for $level in (1..3)
            &[data-level="{$level}"]
                margin-left ($level * 50)px
```

How can I sort this out?

Link to [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyVdqL)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can escape the quote marks:

```
&[data-level=\"{$level}\"]
```

Comment: doesn't work... the result is without quotes:

 `ul.site-map li[data-level=1] {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
ul.site-map li[data-level=2] {
  margin-left: 100px;
}
ul.site-map li[data-level=3] {
  margin-left: 150px;
}
`

Comment: that's strange... my local gulp compiles without quotes... may be i should install new version... thanks!